# How to create user interface for prolog program

Tags: prolog

I am creating a game based on prolog logic base and i would like to create a user interface for it. Any ideas what programming language integrates with prolog?

Comment: You could consider using [Yield Prolog](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yieldprolog/) which is supposed to let you embed Prolog code in Python, C#, or Javascript. I've never tried it. But I can recommend [SWI-Prolog's http library(http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=httpserver), in case you want to go the browser based route. It's quite capable, I think. The SWI website and online docs are written with the package, I believe. Anniepoo's tutorial (linked below in her answer) gives a good start.

Answer (score 6):

If you use SWI-Prolog, and know Qt, you could use QtCreator designer. An example is online [here](https://github.com/CapelliC/fdqueens).

Answer (score 6):

It might seem a little counter-intuitive at first, but I actually recommend making a web-based GUI. Once you think it through (and check out the http functionality of eclipse clp, http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/http/index.html) you'll realize that Prolog is actually rather well suited as language to write an application server in. I've done that to great success and it avoid the uphill battle of convincing someone to look at a non-standard UI framework. Plus it enables mobile right away and separates concerns really well.

Here is a minimalist example. When you run it (`eclipse -s http.pl`, then invoke `runserver`), you can open your browser at localhost:8000 to invoke the route predicates defined in processURL below:

http.pl:

```
:- lib(http),
    use_module(http_method).

runserver :-
    http_server(8000).
```

http_method.pl:

```
:- module(http_method).

http_method("GET", Url, Params, Contents, 200, [contentLength(CL), contentType(mt(text, html))]):-
    printf("%w\n", [http_method(Url, Params)]), flush(output),
    http_process(Url, Contents),
    string_length(Contents, CL).

http_process(Url, Contents) :-
    split_string(Url, "/", "/", L),
    printf("URL split: %w\n", [L]), flush(output),
    processURL(L, Contents).

processURL([""], "Hello World!").
processURL(["route1"], "You are at /route1").
```

Comment: Is this SWI-Prolog ? I've never seen this syntax `call(http_process(Url, Contents))@eclipse,`

Comment: Good catch! Thanks. It is indeed eclipse clp and not swi-prolog. I've updated the answer and included a link to the http lib. Also, that special syntax was actually not necessary in this example, so I've removed it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can use SWi-Prolog with XPCE.
Also, there is a C# interface with SWI-Prolog.

Answer (score 2):

If you use SWI-Prolog you can use QtCreator, XPCE, or use a web interface.
You could also write in Swing (Java) and use JPL interface or C++ and use CPL interface
or C# interface and use swicli.
Web interface tutorial http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/html/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I see several possible ways:

1. Web-interface using Prolog-based server
2. GUI via specific Prolog implementation features
3. External language interface via specific Prolog implementation features
4. Interprocess communication via sockets between Prolog and some other language (if supported by Prolog system)
5. Command-line (stdin/stdout) communication between Prolog and some other language

Web-interface using Prolog-based server can be nice, but usually web-servers are not the main point of focus of Prolog system developers, so it can be not well-tested and may not support all HTTP features, or HTTPS, or compression...  Also there are possible security issues. Making Prolog server local-accessible only and having another web-server communicating to outer world is probably a good idea (using Prolog server in a manner that database servers are usually used for the web).

As for GUI in Prolog, XPCE or Qt can be used with SWI-Prolog, as other answers mentioned. Other implementations can also have GUI facilities.

But I think that every tool should be used to do tasks for which it excels, and Prolog is arguably not the best tool to do user interfaces or web-servers, so I'd choose options 3, 4, or 5 from my list.

For Prolog systems I use:

- **ECLiPSe CLP**

  1. There is a HTTP server implementation, but it looks outdated (mentions Netscape etc.) and "The MIME and HTTP grammar is not complete and may fail parsing some sentences generated by existing browsers".
  2. No facilities to create GUI with Prolog.
  3. Interfaces to work with Tcl/Tk, C, C++, Java.
  4. Sockets support.
- **B-Prolog**

  1. No HTTP server implementation.
  2. MS Windows-only CGLIB: "A Constraint-based Graphics Library for B-Prolog".
  3. Interfaces to work with C and Java.
  4. Sockets support.

Of course, command-line (stdin/stdout) communication between Prolog and some other language should work for every Prolog system, but it can be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Use xpce Prolog,an embedded library of swi prolog for interfaces.